# Django: How to store in the database a list of dates and the songs someone listen that day?

Tags: python, django, database, model

Imagine I have 2 models Song and Person:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And I want to create a field inside the Person model to store a list of the dates this person listens to music and what songs they listen to.

```
2019-10-2 -> (Song 3, Song 25, Song 50)
2019-10-3 -> (Song 4, Song 5, Song 12)
2019-10-7 -> (Song 77, Song 22, Song 11)
```

The ManyToMany field seems to work for linking to one or multiple instances of another model but doesn't seem to be useful for this case.

Is there any type of field could I use? Or is there any other way to store all that information?

The only other way I can think of is creating a model like this and have a table with all the songs that everyone has listened to and link them to each user and add the date:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person)
    date = models.DateField()
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)
```

I'm pretty new to databases and django so im not really sure which is the proper way of storing this kind of information. Under the person's profile or in a different table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a third model, listens, which links the person and the song and records which date. That way, if your person or song models get more complex, you won't have duplicated data. In general, you want a table for each sort of 'thing' you're recording, in this case you have a person, a song, and a listen, which is a link between the two associated with a date.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Listens(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song, on_delete=models.Cascade)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    person = ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.Cascade)
```

Comment: So this would have one entry per song, instead of one entry per day as my example?

Comment: Yep! and then to get all songs for a given day you would filter the data.

Comment: @AlvaroBataller sorry, I had a typo, I meant to type `DateTimeField()` because recording the date and time both is why you won't get duplicate data.